# How can I Enable/Disable table row contents - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My HTML I'm having controls inside table as :-

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in MyTblDataList">
     <td>
       <input id="chkBoxClass" type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox-inline" ng-model="r.BoardID" />
     </td>
     <td>
        <input id="txtClass" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="r.BoardName" value="{{r.BoardName}}" disabled />
     </td>
     <td>
        <input id="btnEditClass" type="button" class="btn-xs btn-info" value="Edit" ng-click="EditUpdateChange('btnEditClass','btnUpdateClass','txtClass',true)" />
        <input id="btnUpdateClass" type="button" class="btn-xs btn-success" value="{{btnUpdate}}" ng-click="UpdateClass('btnEditClass','btnUpdateClass','txtClass', r.BoardID )" hidden />
        <input id="btnDeleteClass" type="button" class="btn-xs btn-danger" value="Delete" />
      </td>
```

I'm using my function to show/Hide and Disable the textbox:-

```
$scope.EditUpdateChange = function (btnEditID, btnUpdateID, txtEditID, value) {
            if (value) {
                $('#' + btnEditID).hide();
                $('#' + btnUpdateID).show();
            }
            else {
                $('#' + btnEditID).show();
                $('#' + btnUpdateID).hide();
            }
            //$('#' + txtEditID).prop('disabled', !value);
            $(this).closest('tr').disabled = !value;
        }
```

My problem is even though I click on Edit button in second or third row. My first row always go enable and disable. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Also is there a better way of doing this using Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For hiding and showing elements in angular, I think you should use the built-in directives `ng-show`, `ng-hide` or `ng-if`.

As the name suggests, `ng-show` and `ng-hide` show or hide the element based on the expression provided. Note that they are still in the DOM, they just aren't visible right now. `ng-if` insert or remove the element from the DOM, instead of showing or hiding.

For disabling the row, you can use the `ng-disabled` directive.

So, in your code, you could use:

```
<tr ng-disabled="!r.BoardID"> <!-- Didn't test, but I think this will disable the whole row, including the checkbox, so you may want to move the ng-disabled to the input itself -->
  <input id="btnEditClass" type="button" class="btn-xs btn-info" value="Edit" ng-click="EditUpdateChange()" ng-hide="r.BoardID" />
  <input id="btnUpdateClass" type="button" class="btn-xs btn-success" value="{{btnUpdate}}" ng-click="UpdateClass()" ng-show="r.BoardID" />
</tr>
```

In general, I think you don't really need to use JQuery when developing an Angular application.

## Edit 1

The status you want then:

1. At first, edit and delete button are available and the textbox is disabled
2. When edit button is clicked:

   - Enable the textbox
   - Show the update button
   - Hide the edit button

Alright, so the code for this would be like that:

**Row in html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in MyTblDataList">
  <td>
     <input id="chkBoxClass" type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox-inline" ng-model="r.BoardID" />
  </td>
  <td>
     <input ng-disabled="!r.isEditing" id="txtClass" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="r.BoardName" value="{{r.BoardName}}"/>
     <!-- Will disable on null, false and undefined -->
 </td>
 <td>
    <input ng-click="onEdit($index)" ng-if="!r.isEditing" id="btnEditClass" type="button" class="btn-xs btn-info" value="Edit"/> 
    <!-- $index is a variable provided by ng-repeat -->
    <!-- Similar as above, but will be inserted in the DOM instead of disabled. -->

    <input ng-click="onUpdate($index)" ng-if="r.isEditing" id="btnUpdateClass" type="button" class="btn-xs btn-success" value="{{btnUpdate}}"/>

    <!-- 
      If you want to use show/hide, you would use:
        Edit btn: ng-hide="r.isEditing"
        Update btn: nh-show="r.isEditing"
    -->
    <input id="btnDeleteClass" type="button" class="btn-xs btn-danger" value="Delete" />
 </td>
</tr>
```

**variable and functions needed in JS**

```
function onEdit(index){
  MyTblDataList[index].isEditing = true;
}

function onUpdate(index){
  // You may want to do something with the new data, maybe some validation or so
  MyTblDataList[index].isEditing = false;
}
```

When updating the data in the controller, the change should be reflected in the view. To ilustrate this, I have created a [Plunker with your code](https://plnkr.co/edit/9yp6Iq?p=preview). In this plunker:

- I use `vm as syntax` (you can search about this, but it is a better aproach to link the data to the controller through `var vm = this` instead of accessing the scope directly)
- Made one field editable at one time
- If you leave without clicking the Update button, the changes are discarted.

I have choosed to use the `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` and `ng-hide` to select what to show because as `ng-if` remove the content from the HTML, it remove the watchers manteined by Angular. Note that if there is an excesive amount of watchers, performance is affected.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think I'm not able to explain. Actually I want this:- First Edit & Delete are visible and textbox is disabled .Now When I click Edit the edit button should be hidden and Update button should be visible and textbox should be editable. Vice Versa on Update click.

Comment: Okay, I get now. I will update my answer. Just a moment.

Comment: @Deepak, I have updated the answer. does this fit your needs now?

Comment: Ah! Just what I want. Haven't applied the code but the plunker seems perfect! Do I have to apply the vm as syntax? I'm using the same controller in my entire project. Will it not create a problem if I apply the vm syntax?

Comment: You can continue using the $scope. It's more a recommendation to avoid using `$scope`, using it will work but is preferably not using it. 

In the Controllers section of [John Papa Angular 1 Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#controllers), he explains why to avoid it.